# Restoring MSSQL back-ups to Oracle 12c

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup, oracle-12c, etl

I currently have an Oracle 12c DW that has several data sources of varying types (MSSQL, Oracle, MS Access, PostgreSQL, etc.) being moved into it as part of our existing ETL process.  We have FME (safe.com) currently configured to do the bulk of it. For the most case this is functioning well.

However I have one data source that poses an interesting issue.  It is in production with no reporting/slave/replication strategy and it's resources/security prevents us from directly connecting to it. The only manner in which this data is available is through backups.  It is a MSSQL 2008 server with a weekly full backup and incremental backups daily between those weekly full backups.  I need to get this information into the Oracle 12c DW.  As far as I'm aware (currently speaking with FME support) FME isn't capable of directly reading backups and I'm likely unable to use FME short of restoring the backups to a different server and using FME to move from that intermediate server.

So I wanted to ask a 2 part question:

1) Can I restore a MSSQL full backup to an Oracle 12c database?

2) Can I restore incremental MSSQL backups to an Oracle 12c database?

And if this can't be done directly, is anyone aware of some workarounds?  I'd like to do this in a manner that can be scheduled (no manual work required) if at all possible.

My research shows that you can take some manual steps in Oracle developer to do this (might work for a one time migration, I'm unsure if I can schedule this process):
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm

As a last resort, I'm pretty sure I can get an intermediate server with MSSQL on it that I can restore the backups to and then connect to it with FME.  However that has some costs associated to it (MSSQL license and hardware) that I'm trying to avoid for my client.

Comment: You cannot restore any type of SQL Server backup on Oracle database. You might have to move data this is your only option.

Comment: How big is that SQL Server database? If it doesn't exceed 10GB you could get away with installing SQL Server Express (which has no license costs)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I think 35GB, so that won't be an option.  Thanks though, I think no method is my answer and I'll look into my work arounds.

Comment: Curious what the down vote was for.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no way to do this without first restoring to MSSQL.